How to pronounce "completed"?
Is the d silent? Is there any special rule for verbs that end with "e"?
Or maybe there is some past tense form, or context, in which "complete" remains "complete"?

Where? What dialect or variety of English? Completed, rotated, deleted, (etc) all have a terminal 'd' that is pronounced in most prestigious/educated/cultured English variants - no 'special rule'.

"Job completed" for example - is it correct to say "job com-plee-ted"?

Yes, it's correct. In fact, to me it's so obviously correct that I wonder if you're really asking another question. For example, you can say "job [is] complete" in certain contexts, but then it's not a verb, it's an adjective. Where it is clearly a verb (I completed the job last night) the terminal 'd' is pronounced normally as @MichaelHarvey has explained.

Yes, maybe as an adjective! Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Some regional accents, or hurried speech, might cause the final syllable to be poorly articulated, like "complet'd." So you might hear something that sounds identical to "complete," but it would be advisable to a learner to articulate it fully.

"Complete" and "completed" are different parts of speech/tenses of the same word
As an adjective, the word is "complete", with the comparative "completer" and superlative "completest".
"Completely" is the adverb.
As a verb, "complete" is the first and second person present, "completes" is the 3rd person present, "completed" is the past tense, and "completing" is the present participle of gerund.
The "d" in "completed" would normally be pronounced in most English dialects, but, as always, it depends on the following sounds. While I can't think of a particular sound combination that would cause me to drop the "d", that doesn't mean there isn't one.
